# How should I express total ordering on a type with a lifetime parameter while allowing comparisons with different lifetimes?

Tags: rust

I'm creating a map-like data structure in which every value provides a means of retrieving its unique key via implementing a trait.  The keys are expected to reference one or more fields of the corresponding value (or just reference stack data or whatever when created temporarily to e.g. look up a value in the map).  The keys clearly need to be `Ord` for the data structure to work with them correctly.  The data structure is currently implemented using a sorted vector.

I run into lifetime difficulties when I need to compare keys which have different lifetimes.  For example, one key is a parameter and another key is from data already in the map, or one key is a parameter and another key is retrieved from a separate data value parameter.  (In my real code I didn't run into this problem until I wrote a `replace` method corresponding to the latter example, but in the minimal repro I created for this question I'm also running into it for a simple `get` method which is more like the former example; I'm not sure why my original `get` method didn't run into this problem, I guess I changed something after I implemented it.)

Here's some stripped down code:

```
trait HasKey {
    type Key<'a>: Ord where Self: 'a;
    fn get_key<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Key<'a>;
}

struct Data {
    id: String,
    // more data
}

#[derive(Ord, PartialOrd, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct DataKey<'a>(&'a str); // might also contain more fields

struct Map<T>(Vec<T>) where T: HasKey;

impl HasKey for Data {
    type Key<'a> = DataKey<'a>;
    fn get_key<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Key<'a> {
        DataKey(&self.id)
    }
}

impl<T> Map<T> where T: HasKey {
    fn compare_keys<'a>(left: &T::Key<'a>, right: &T::Key<'a>) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        left.cmp(right)
    }
    
    fn replace<'a>(&self, key: &T::Key<'a>, value: T) {
        Self::compare_keys(key, &value.get_key());
        // if keys are equal, replace old value with new value in place
        // otherwise remove key and insert value, moving only items in between
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = Map(vec![
        // test data already sorted; normally Map constructor would sort it
        Data { id: "bar".to_string() },
        Data { id: "foo".to_string() },
    ]);
    m.replace(DataKey("foo"), Data { id: "foobar".to_string() })
}
```

The compiler complains as follows:

```
error[E0597]: `value` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:44:35
43 |     fn replace<'a>(&self, key: T::Key<'a>, value: T) {
   |                --                          ----- binding `value` declared here
   |                |
   |                lifetime `'a` defined here
44 |         Self::compare_keys(&key, &value.get_key());
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                   |
   |                                   borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                   argument requires that `value` is borrowed for `'a`
...
47 |     }
   |     - `value` dropped here while still borrowed
```

After much consideration and troubleshooting, it finally dawned on me that the reason `value` is required to be borrowed for `'a` is that `compare_keys` is using the same lifetime for both of its arguments, meaning that callers need to provide arguments with matching lifetimes.  That is definitely not what I intended, so I try to rewrite `compare_keys` to accept arguments with different lifetimes:

```
    fn compare_keys<'a, 'b>(left: &T::Key<'a>, right: &T::Key<'b>) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        left.cmp(right)
    }
```

Now the compiler effectively makes the same complaint about the call `left.cmp(right)`, saying both that `'a` must outlive `'b` *and* that `'b` must outlive `'a`, so it suggests that I combine them into a single lifetime (i.e. go back to what I had before).  At this point I realize that `Ord` requires `PartialOrd<Self>` and `Eq` (which in turn requires `PartialEq<Self>`), and I'm pretty sure that `Self` there includes any lifetime parameters, leading me to conclude that `Ord` is creating the restriction that I can only compare keys whose data references have the same lifetime.

This is when I realize that `Ord` doesn't take a parameter like `PartialOrd` does, but as a workaround I try changing my trait so that it requires keys to be `PartialOrd` instead so that I can specify that the type to compare against can have a different lifetime, like so:

```
trait HasKey {
    type Key<'a>: for<'b> PartialOrd<Self::Key<'b>> where Self: 'a;
    fn get_key<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Key<'a>;
}
```

This requires me to provide my own `PartialOrd` and `PartialEq` implementations instead of relying on the default ones, but they're trivial and not a big deal.  I also modify `compare_keys` to call `partial_cmp` instead of `cmp` and just `unwrap` the result.  That finally makes the compiler happy.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e33fef209793dcaa6aaec6bf45b7bf76) with the initial code and the changes/fixes in comments.

My questions:

1. Did I draw the right conclusion that the errors are effectively caused by `Ord` requiring the lifetime parameters of my key structures to match, or does this actually have some other problem that I missed (but that my workaround still resolves)?
2. Are there other/better solutions than I came up with?  Is there a better way for me to define methods like `replace`?  Is there a better way for me to express that keys need to have a total ordering with respect to their values but not their lifetimes?

Naively, I want `Ord` to take a generic parameter, but since `Ord` implies `Eq` then `Eq` would also need to take a generic parameter (or maybe not?.. though that feels weird), and I understand that that wouldn't really make sense since the whole point of `Eq` is to express that a thing will always equal itself (in addition to `PartialEq` requirements).  I feel like there's some sort of gap here, but I can't quite express its definition, and that makes me think that there's something here that I'm either not seeing or not understanding well.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I draw the right conclusion that the errors are effectively caused by Ord requiring the lifetime parameters of my key structures to match, or does this actually have some other problem that I missed (but that my workaround still resolves)?

Yes, you drew the right conclusions. Good work!

> Are there other/better solutions than I came up with?

The reason it usually works without special attention is because of [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html#variance). When the type is covariant, we can shrink the lifetime, and so we pick the "lowest common denominator" lifetime to both and compare it. But generics associated types are always invariant over their parameters (meaning they cannot shrink or grow), since they may be used with invariant types. Unfortunately there isn't currently way to specify that it must be covariant. [As I answered recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77022284/7884305) we can though provide a method that fills the place of what done automatically by covariance:

```rust
trait HasKey {
    type Key<'a>: Ord
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn get_key<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Key<'a>;

    fn shrink_key_lifetime<'a: 'b, 'b, 'c>(key: &'c Self::Key<'a>) -> &'c Self::Key<'b>;
}

struct Map<T>(Vec<T>)
where
    T: HasKey;

impl HasKey for Data {
    type Key<'a> = DataKey<'a>;
    fn get_key<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Key<'a> {
        DataKey(&self.id)
    }

    fn shrink_key_lifetime<'a: 'b, 'b, 'c>(key: &'c Self::Key<'a>) -> &'c Self::Key<'b> {
        key
    }
}

impl<T> Map<T>
where
    T: HasKey,
{
    fn compare_keys<'a>(left: &T::Key<'a>, right: &T::Key<'a>) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        left.cmp(right)
    }

    fn replace<'a>(&self, key: &T::Key<'a>, value: T) {
        Self::compare_keys(
            T::shrink_key_lifetime(key),
            T::shrink_key_lifetime(&value.get_key()),
        );
        // if keys are equal, replace old value with new value in place
        // otherwise remove key and insert value, moving only items in between
    }
}
```

This allows you to use `Ord` as well as derive it. If you don't want the users to mess with this method, you can split the trait and have it in a supertrait and provide a macro to implement it.

Comment: I should have guessed that variance would be relevant here. In a way I'm glad that I bumped into a problem with it [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75751455/2171706), because although I understand the concept in isolation, I still have trouble applying it to real world situations, and if I keep bumping into it from different angles and working my way through it then I'll eventually be able to wrap my head all the way around it. This solution is especially helpful because it shows explicitly what covariance would normally allow automatically. This is exactly what I was missing here, thanks!